# Initial state with knockout.js and Spring MVC / JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, knockout.js

I'm just wondering how best to go about this. I want to load an initial page which will be generated via a JSP, this will be my knockout view. But it seems a shame to then have to immediately do an Ajax request on page load to go and get the data to set the field values.

What would be ideal is if I could load the initial view with values set and then get knockout to initialise from this. I'm not sure if this is possible though? Another thought I had was to generate an empty view and then put a  section at the bottom where I write the JSON output equivalent to the Ajax request I'm trying to avoid.

Surely someone else has solved this same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply template out the json data into javascript when your view is being rendered and have your knockout access that data (or pass it into the viewmodel).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = /*INSERT TEMPLATED DATA HERE*/;

    var model = new Model(data);
    ko.applyBindings(model);
</script>
```

**Edit:**

I usually build my viewmodels for knockout in the general templated approach to support inital state as well as delayed state such as from an ajax call. This will function well with the approach I listed above:

```
function Model(data, parent)
{
    var self = this;
    self.parent = parent;

    self.Load = function(data) {
        if (data) {
            //initialize data here
        }
    };
    self.Load(data); //call initially here in case of initial state


    //other functionality
}
```

Comment: This is one of the approaches I was considering. I wasn't sure about having to output JSON on the web page but I guess it's either that or an ajax call.

Comment: Those are your two options =P

Comment: I see this thread is now 7+ years old but I wonder if the answer is any different. I have a Zend Framework 3/Doctrine2 project with a lot of jQuery involved, and I think it's time to get my Javascript better organized. I'm new to KO and find it attractive but wondering how to get started, e.g., when doing something like an "edit" action where you already have your entity in the view layer as PHP data. Turn it to JSON and render it so KO can consume it?  seems inefficient (fetch, serialize, unserialize...) . Another xhr call just to fetch data you could've brought along for the ride? bleh.

Comment: what if you were to go ahead and populate your form via PHP, and with jQuery/KO initialize your model with data taken from the form's initial state?

Comment: @David That is another way of approaching it. This is a very old thread indeed haha. You could certainly populate a form with hidden fields and then map those back into your view model. This isn't too different fundamentally than serializing JSON. In either case, you are materializing the data into the page client side as part of the request rather than making a separate ajax request to fetch the data. Having had another 6 years of experience since then, I would opt much more to leverage ajax to make the request and provide user a quicker initial load time and take advantage of browser caching

Comment: @FeistyMango so you're saying you think another request to the server is worth it, right? I am just thought-experimenting here, but one concern is that let's say you serve a page with an empty form, and immediately make another request to get the data to populate it. Will that produce that unpleasant jumpy effect in the browser?

Comment: @David It may be worth it depending on the amount of json data you need to serialize down. Hard to say without knowing specifics. As a general rule, I would opt for making the ajax call.

You overcome the visual issues by leveraging sound UX principals. Even something as simple as a loading overlay indicator that appears before content is rendered would suffix to prevent the "jumpy" issue. Facebook tackles this by placing an image of a generic looking wall post that is replaced with the real content once the ajax call completes.

Comment: that's what makes this business so much fun -- you get to exercise those neurons!